# Open pdf in cordova using file-transfer and file-opener2 plugin

Tags: cordova, pdf

I am using Cordova with the cordova-plugin-file-transfer and cordova-plugin-file-opener2

I am testing on an android phone. It would appear to download the file and the code reports that the file is stored here (e.g. entry.toURL()): file:///data/user/0/com.domain.app/cache/downloaded.pdf

However if I browse the file system I can not find this location to verify the file exists. I cannot even find data/user

When the fileopener2.open is called it launches the pdf app but then reports can't open file.

I a not getting any errors to indicate that anything is failing.

I am wondering if the location where it is being stored is protected and therefore it can't be opened.

Any help is appreciated.

Here's my code

```
    downloadFile: function () {

    window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 5 * 1024 * 1024, function (fs) {
        alert('file system open: ' + fs.name);

        var url = 'http://www.website.co.uk/test.pdf';

        fs.root.getFile('downloaded.pdf', { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
            app.download(fileEntry, url, true);

        }, function () {
            alert('onErrorCreateFile');
        });

    }, function () {
        alert('onErrorLoadFs');
    });
},


download: function (fileEntry, uri, readBinaryData) {

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var fileURL = fileEntry.toURL();

    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        fileURL,
        function (entry) {
            alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());

            cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
                entry.toURL(),
                'application/pdf'
            );
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("download error source " + error.source);
            alert("download error target " + error.target);
            alert("upload error code" + error.code);
        },
        null,
        {
        }
    );
},
```

Comment: I know that this is an old question, but for the sake of other people that are trying to get this right and are having this problem, let me explain what I believe is going wrong with this code. You are using conflicting methods of creating the file, both getFile and FileTransfer download method are trying to create a file. The getFile creates it first and then you pass that URL for the same file on to the download method, but it cannot create the file with this URL because it is locked. Either use getFile with an ajax call to populate or use FileTransfer download method. Not both.